# How to show the following limit exist by definition?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

How do you show the following limit exist by definition?

[image]

I know that $0<((x-1)^2)+(y-1)^2))^{1/2}<δ$ and need to show that $|f(x,y)-(-1/3)|<ε.$

But I got stuck at $|\frac{-1}{x^2+xy+y^2} + \frac{1}{3}|<ε$. How should I proceed with $|x-1|$ or $|y-1|$?

Have been struggling for 3 hrs. Can anyone help please?

Comment: What is the function $f(x,y)$?

Comment: $(y-x)/((x^3)-(y^3))$

Comment: Hint: Factorise the denominator: $x^3-y^3$.

Comment: And I got $|\frac{-1}{x^2+xy+y^2}+ \frac{1}{3}| < ε$. Then I have no idea how to make it into something related to the $|x-1|$ or $|y-1|$

Answer (score 0):

First try to simplify $\frac{y-x}{x^3-y^3}$.

Hint: $x^3-y^3=(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2)$.

Comment: What is the next step? I got $|\frac{-1}{x^2+xy+y^2} + \frac{1}{3}|<ε$. How do you proceed with $|x-1|$ or $|y-1|$ here?

Comment: Can you observe that $\frac{-1}{x^2+xy+y^2} < \frac{-1}{ (x-1)^2  +(y-1)^2 }$?

Comment: Sorry. I can't. Please tell me why.

Comment: Think about it...whether it is true? If yes then you can use the statement to finish up your proof.

Comment: I am not sure about $xy$.

Comment: See it...$(x-1)^2 + (y-1)^2=x^2 +y^2 -2x-2y+2$. For x and y of the same parity, $x^2+xy+y^2>x^2 +y^2 -2x-2y+2$. So ...

Comment: Or do you mean that since we don't know $xy$, which could be positive or negative and is more dominant, so $x^2+y^2+xy<(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29580/discussion-between-lawrence-lo-and-chuks).